# How many classes of scriptures understanding is necessary to understand Puranas?

Tags: scripture, puranas

It is well known that all stories in the Puranas shouldn't be taken literally (or physically). Many (such) stories of Puranas are symbolic of facts or phenomena from other classes of scriptures.

I came to know that, to understand the stories of Puranas properly, there should be expertise in at least six classes of scriptures. They are the scriptures of **Jyotish, Yagna, Mantra, Dharma, Tattva, and Yoga**. So, one needs to understand these six classes of scriptures well before interpreting Puranas.

How many such classes (of scriptures) are there in total, whose understanding is necessary to properly understand Puranas?

Comment: What if the title is edited to- how many classes of scriptures’ understanding is necessary to understand Puranas

Comment: @Archit thanks...

Comment: Looks like this question is open to all kind of interpretations. Do you want to make it specific like maybe "How many classes of scriptures understanding is necessary to understand Puranas, as per other scriptures or gurus?" I don't want this useful post to be flooded with all opinions which decrease the value of this post.

Comment: @Mr_Green If some one shows a class of interpretation, they should provide its validity by using any story from puranas that is valid with the type of interpretation they are using.